# React Native app is not running on physical device

Tags: android, react-native, crash, android-emulator

I am running a react native app but this app is running fine on emulator but not running on physical device.
App is installed successfully and opened on physical device, but on opening it shows white screen for a while after that it is crashed/closed.
Unable to find reason.

When I am running project through android studio on physical device, it is giving me this error:

```
E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libflipper.so caused by: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Backtrace" referenced by "/data/app/com.project-xyz==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so"... result: 0
```

StackTrace is:

```
    D/SoLoader: About to load: libflipper.so
    libflipper.so not found on /data/data/com.project/lib-main
    libflipper.so found on /data/app/com.project-xyz==/lib/arm64
    Not resolving dependencies for libflipper.so
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Backtrace" referenced by "/data/app/com.project-xyz==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:938)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1631)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:405)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:77)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:50)
        at com.facebook.soloader.ApplicationSoSource.loadLibrary(ApplicationSoSource.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:860)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582)
        at com.facebook.flipper.android.EventBase.<clinit>(EventBase.java:19)
        at com.facebook.flipper.android.FlipperThread.run(FlipperThread.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is to Update FLIPPER_VERSION.
Second is to make sure that your device is connected to your system, react native (in debug mode) creates a localhost on the system and runs the app on device (device connected to system through a wire). If you will disconnect the device, it will not work properly.

Answer (score 8):

Update `FLIPPER_VERSION` (latest actually 0.116.0) in `android/gradle.properties` should fix this issue.

Comment: 5 hours of debugging and swearing until I found your answer which solved everything. THANK YOU.

Comment: <3 haha thanks for this feedback. You made my day

Comment: Thanks - latest version can be taken from the [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flipper)

Answer (score 0):

On some phones, after plugging in the usb cable, select "File Transfer option" on your phone. Also make sure that "Usb debugging" is enabled in the "Developer options" menu.

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting your device to the computer and check logcat in android studio. You should be able to see the logs.

Comment: please have a look on question again, it is giving me an error on running on device through android studio:

E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libflipper.so caused by: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Backtrace" referenced by "/data/app/com.project==/lib/arm64/libflipper.so"... result: 0